# Error: node: command not found Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Tags: python, shell, jenkins

I wrote `print('Hello world!')` in the shell of Jenkins.
[image]
The error shows below:
[image]

Can anyone help with the issue? Thanks

Comment: Check whether python is correctly installed in your system by typing the following in cmd ```python --version```

Comment: I type ```python --version``` it returns: python2.7.18; type ```python3 --version``` it returns python3.7.7

Answer (score 1):

You are ***NOT*** executing python program in the given screenshot, instead you are executing a shell script. It's evident from the error screenshot where it states executable as

```
[python] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkinsxxxxxxxxx.sh
```

python is the name of your jenkins host (and job too looking at your logs), presumably you are confused with that. Try following instead

```
echo "Hello world"
```

and it'll print alright. Basically any and every shell script command will work just fine.